# Footer image is not showing up

Tags: xslt, footer, xsl-fo, dita

I am trying to display image in footer in PDF generation using *DITA-OT* in body pages only. My image is not showing in the output. Here is my code.

**static-content.xsl:-**

```
<xsl:template name="insertBodyOddFooter">

        <fo:static-content flow-name="odd-body-footer">
            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__body__odd__footer">
                <xsl:call-template name="insertVariable">
                    <xsl:with-param name="theVariableID" select="'Body odd footer'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="theParameters">
                        <heading>
                            <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="__body__odd__footer__heading">
                                <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="current-header"/>
                            </fo:inline>
                        </heading>
                        <pagenum>
                            <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="__body__odd__footer__pagenum">
                                <fo:page-number/>
                            </fo:inline>
                        </pagenum>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>

            </fo:block>
                <!-- for footer image -->

                            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="footer_image">
                                <fo:external-graphic src="url(Customization/OpenTopic/common/artwork/footer_img.png)"/>
                            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
```

**static-content-attr.xsl:-**

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="footer_image">
     <!-- <xsl:attribute name="padding-left">10</xsl:attribute> -->
     <xsl:attribute name="position">absolute</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="content-width">scale-to-fit</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="space-before.conditionality">retain</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="scaling">uniform</xsl:attribute> 
     <xsl:attribute name="width">100%</xsl:attribute> 
     </xsl:attribute-set>
```

*Where am I going wrong ? I did the same in header and its working*.

Comment: Do you have a region named `odd-body-footer` in the `fo:simple-page-master` that is being used for that page?  Not having a corresponding region is a common mistake, plus most of the names in your code have the words in the order 'body', 'odd', then 'footer'.

Comment: Run the toolkit and export the FO, analyze the FO. You (and us) cannot guess from your templates what may be happening

Comment: @TonyGraham Sorry , I didn't get you . And most of the names ( 'body', 'odd',  'footer' )are by default in the pdf2 plugin.

Comment: @KevinBrown Simply I add image url in static-content.xsl and its attribute on static-content-attr.xsl . Anything more I have to do for showing up image? Is it different from header? I did the same in header and its showing...coz other things are perfect.

Comment: You have `flow-name="odd-body-footer"`, but also `use-attribute-sets="__body__odd__footer"`, etc., `name="insertBodyOddFooter"`, and `select="'Body odd footer'"`.  Is the `region-name` in the `fo:simple-page-master` similarly `body-odd-footer`?